# Magento 2 Braintree Module How Do You Handle Credit Card Errors In Your Cart?

Tags: checkout, payment, payment-gateway

I am using the Braintree Module that comes with M2.1.3 but it doesn't deal with CC errors with any sort of useful messaging. I wondered if other's had found a way to pass on useful error messages to the customer e.g. Expiry Date or Insufficient Funds etc.

Answer (score 2):

Braintree payment method in Magento 2.1.x versions based on [Braintree Hosted Fields](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/overview/javascript/v2). Card validation is provided by Braintree JS SDK, Magento Braintree template just customize this errors.

[image]

But, you can extend js component, specify different template view, and override error messages.

Also, you can customize css styles for errors, you just need to override: `hosted-error` and `braintree-hosted-fields-invalid` css classes.